# Spark Dataframe - unique ids with last data?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I have a dataframe like

```
id | col1 | col2 | ... | col50
30 | new  | new  | ... | new
25 | old  | old  | ... | old
25 | old  | old  | ... | old
25 | new  | new  | ... | new
57 | old  | old  | ... | old
57 | new  | new  | ... | new
```

How can I distinctly select each id with the newest data? So the output should be:

```
id | col1 | col2 | ... | col50
30 | new  | new  | ... | new
25 | new  | new  | ... | new
57 | new  | new  | ... | new
```

Basically I'd need to select all the distict id's but with not the first, but the last entry.

Comment: can you please elaborate your requirement, why can't you just apply filter of new?

Comment: Because I don't know which data is new and which is old. The dataframe I showed is an illustration, the real data is not `old` and `new`...Or to be precise, I only know that the last entry of each id is the latest. That's what I need.